# How to split a string and make particular data only to be stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, split

I have a string like

```
var directoryPath = "file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.ftptranfer949961/cache/1467013143014.png"
```

in the above variable I would like storing only a particular string like this

```
var updatedPath = "/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.ftptranfer949961/cache/"
```

I have tried the `split()` method but I don't know how to store the particular path in my **updatedPath** variable.

Comment: Get index of the word 'cache', then slice the string from index 6 to that index + 5 or +6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is something like this:

```js
var directoryPath = "file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.ftptranfer949961/cache/1467013143014.png";
var stringToReplace = 'file://';
var lastIndexOfSlash = directoryPath.lastIndexOf('/');
var offset = stringToReplace.length;
var updatedPath = directoryPath.substr(offset, lastIndexOfSlash - offset + 1);
alert(updatedPath);
```

This will set the updatePath variable to the directoryPath withouth the string you wish to remove (i.e. "file://") and remove the last part of the url where the `.png` location is set.